# Tornado redirect to a different domain

Tags: redirect, tornado

I have a Tornado server and I want to redirect people coming from a certain country to a totally different domain. It depends on their IP, and I need it to work for every URI chosen. So for example if someone goes to www.mysite.com/about from a British IP, I want to redirect her to www.mysite.uk/about.

I tried adding the function initialize() to the BaseHandler, but according to what I've seen, It's impossible to finish from the init.

I checked out RedirectHandler, but it changes only the URI, and not the entire domain as I need.

Do you know of any solution within Tornado? (I also use nginx, but don't think it can support checking the ip, finding the locations, and also I have a lot of URIs).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RedirectHandler` works with both absolute and relative urls; why do you think you can't change the domain with it?

You cannot redirect (or send any response) from `initialize()`, but you can from `prepare()`. It sounds like this is the right place for what you want to do:

```
def prepare(self):
    if should_redirect(self.request):
        self.redirect(new_domain, self.request.uri)
        raise tornado.web.Finish()
```